# Hide ajax appended html until certain point

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, append

I am using AJAX to load more results from my database.

Here is the basic script:

```
  $('#loadmorebuilds-div').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'includes/loadmorebuilds.php?type=' + type + '&pageIndex=' + pageIndex + '&st=' + searchTerm,
        success: function(html) {
            // append the new results
            $("#buildcontainer").append(html);
            // wait untill all images are loaded before the waterfall function is called
            imagesLoaded( '#buildcontainer', function()
            {
                $("#buildcontainer").waterfall('reflow');
            });
        }
    });
  });
```

The problem is that the newly appended data (html) is shown, but it is overlapping itself untill the images have loaded and then the reflow function is called on the container which makes the items fall into their grid.

I want to only show the appended data AFTER the images have loaded AND the items have been 'reflowed' into the waterfall grid.

I just don't see how to do this.

Thanks. P.S, ImagesLoaded is a library for detecting when all images are loaded and waterfall is a masonry grid style.

EDIT: To clarify, the loaded html contains images that I am checking for the them being loaded.

Comment: I don't know about the JS library you are using but why not `.hide()` the `buildContainer` until after the `waterfall` method has been completed?

Comment: @mattdlockyer I think the images are in the html that gets appended.  I could be wrong....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hide the updated DIV, and then show it when the images have been loaded:

```
  $('#loadmorebuilds-div').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'includes/loadmorebuilds.php?type=' + type + '&pageIndex=' + pageIndex + '&st=' + searchTerm,
        success: function(html) {
            // append the new results
            $("#buildcontainer").append(html).hide();
            // wait untill all images are loaded before the waterfall function is called
            imagesLoaded( '#buildcontainer', function()
            {
                $("#buildcontainer").waterfall('reflow').show();
            });
        }
    });
  });
```

Comment: The div that the items are appended to already contains items. I want the elements to append and simply add to the bottom. Hiding and showing the div defeats the idea of the load more button for my purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Don't append the html until the imagesLoaded callback function is called:

```
$('#loadmorebuilds-div').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'includes/loadmorebuilds.php?type=' + type + '&pageIndex=' + pageIndex + '&st=' + searchTerm,
        success: function(html) {
                // append the new results
                $("#buildcontainer").append(html).css('opacity', 0);

            // wait untill all images are loaded before the waterfall function is called
            imagesLoaded( '#buildcontainer', function()
            {
                $("#buildcontainer").waterfall('reflow').css('opacity', 1);
            });
        }
    });
  });
```

Comment: Yes sorry, images are in the loaded html, will update the question.

Comment: if u dont append images will not load

Comment: Or... See my edit: change opacity. The other answer may cause the callback imagesLoaded to be fired if the html is hidden.

Answer (score 0):

How about append a an empty div with a class and then add the content after waterfall has completed.
That way only the new content fades in.

```
$('#loadmorebuilds-div').click(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'includes/loadmorebuilds.php?type=' + type + '&pageIndex=' + pageIndex + '&st=' + searchTerm,
    success: function(html) {
            // append the new results
            $("#buildcontainer").append('<div class="newcontent"></div>')
            $("#buildcontainer").find('.newcontent').last().html(html).css('opacity', 0);
            imagesLoaded( '#buildcontainer', function() {
            $("#buildcontainer").waterfall('reflow').find('.newcontent').last().css('opacity', 1);
        });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: This works in theory, just trying to get it playing nice with the waterfall library. All elements inside the chosen container are a chosen width. The newcontent div is also being given this so its just one long column. But im sure i a can find a way around it.